# Analytic solution of: ${u}''+\frac{1}{x}{u}'=-\delta e^{u}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to find the analytic solution of 
$${u}''+\frac{1}{x}{u}'=-\delta e^{u}$$
given the homogeneous mixed boundary conditions 
$${u'(0)}=0$$
$$u(1)=0$$

How would one attack such a problem? I have been given that the analytic solution is 
$$u=ln\left ( \frac{8a/\delta }{(ax^2+1)^2} \right )$$ 
where $a$ solves $8a=\delta (a+1)^2$.

---

**My approach (EDITED):**

I was given a hint: use the relation $x=e^{-y}$. I proceeded with that and used the chain-rule as follows
$$(u\circ y)'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}u(y(x))=u'(y(x))y'(x)=u'x=-u'e^{y}$$
$$(u\circ y)''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[u'(y(x))y'(x)]=u''(y(x))[y'(x)]^2+u'(y(x))y''(x)=u''e^{2y}+u'e^{2y}$$
substituting these relations into the ODE yields
$$e^{2y}u''=-\delta e^{u}$$
or in an alternative form
$$u''=-\delta e^{-2y} e^{u}$$

which is separable (**thanks for the help**).

Comment: Isn't $y'(x)=-x^{-1}$?

Comment: @user2520938 Oh... yes! This way the term involving $u'$ cancels. I will edit my approach above. Thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the hint you have been give then you will have the new ode

> $$  e^{-u} \frac{d^2u}{dy^2}= \delta e^{-2y} $$

which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show a different approach to solve the ODE $u''+\frac{1}{x}u'=-\delta e^{u}$. We first multiply both sides by $x$, then differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$
xu''+u'=(xu')'=-\delta xe^{u}
$$
$$
\implies (xu')''=-\delta e^u(1+xu')=\frac{1}{x}(xu')'(1+xu'). \tag{1}
$$
Defining $v:=xu'$, we may rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
v''=\frac{1}{x}v'(1+v) &\implies xv''+v'=2v'+vv' \\
&\implies (xv')'=2v'+\left(\frac{v^2}{2}\right)' \\
&\implies xv'=2v+\frac{v^2}{2}+C_1 \tag{2}
\end{align}
Both $xv'$ and $v=xu'$ vanish at $x=0$, hence $C_1=0$. Integrating again, we obtain
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dv}{v^2+4v}=\int\frac{dx}{2x} &\implies \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{v}{v+4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln x + C_2 \\
&\implies v=-\frac{4ax^2}{1+ax^2}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Replacing $v$ with $xu'$ in $(3)$ and integrating once more, we obtain
$$
u=-2\ln(1+ax^2)+C_3. \tag{4}
$$
The condition $u(1)=0$ implies $C_3=2\ln(1+a)$, so
$$
u=2\ln\left(\frac{1+a}{1+ax^2}\right). \tag{5}
$$
As the final step, we substitute $(5)$ in the ODE to find the relation
$$
8a=\delta(1+a)^2. \tag{6}
$$